# (Tomcat 7) Deployed jar not finding files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jar

I deployed a war file onto a Tomcat 7 instance running on a remote Linux machine and I'm getting FileNotFoundExceptions.

One of the referenced jars in the project, which contains code that I did not write, uses several files (which I have included, but it is not finding). These files are located in the classes folder. It appears the classpath I have set for the project is being ignored by this jar. These files that it uses, e.g. .properties files are external to the jar.

Here is an example of how it is invoking the files:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Key.ser");
```

I was getting these errors when developing the source project in Eclipse. I was able to configure the project to tell it where to find these files via Run Configurations -> Arguments -> Other but the exported .war file appears to not have this bundled with it, only the source project has it. Now I'm seeing them again when trying to deploy the application to Tomcat on another server via war file.

How do I configure the deployed jar file in the deployed Tomcat 7 webapp to find these files that the jar uses? I am loathe to change the code since I did not write it so am really hoping to avoid this.

I am able to get this to work on a local Tomcat 7 running on Windows instance integrated with Eclipse as explained earlier so I'm wondering if maybe this can be duplicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to find the file by simply referencing the file name using `FileOutputStream`. You are correct to place the file in the 'WEB-INF/classes' directory, which will allow it to be located on the classpath.

To load the file, you need to load it as a classpath resource using something similar to this:

```
String classpathLocation = ""Key.ser"";
URL classpathResource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(classpathLocation);

// Or if you want it as an inputstream:
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(classpathLocation);
```

Comment: So it sounds like I'm gonna need to change the code after all, darnit. I'm curious, what is the working directory of the jar set to? Maybe I could just hardlink the file over there or something?

Comment: When running Tomcat as a process or service, the working directory by default will be the Tomcat's installation /bin directory, where the Tomcat7.exe or whatever version is typically launched from.  IF you mean, what is the work directory where jars are extracted, it can be configured. Look at the [tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html) search for 'workDir' for more information.